# Polymorphic entities in Room

Tags: android, sqlite, polymorphism, union, android-room

There are 3 entities in my Room DB:

`Album`, `PhotosMediaItem` and `VideosMediaItem`.

`VideosMediaItem` and `PhotosMediaItem` inherit from `MediaItem`.

`MediaItem` is not an entity in the DB, it's just an abstract base class.

I would like to create a query that returns all the photos and videos media items in a specific album with descending order based on their creation date.

So the query will create a list of MediaItems but with the derived types. (`PhotoMediaItem` or `VideoMediaItem`) in a polymorphic way.

Here's what I've tried:

```java
    @Query("SELECT * FROM PhotosMediaItem WHERE PhotosMediaItem = :albumId " +
        "UNION SELECT * FROM VideosMediaItem WHERE VideosMediaItem = :albumId" +
        " ORDER by CreationDate DESC")
    List<MediaItem> getAllMediaInAlbum(int albumId);
```

This won't work obviously, because it tries to initiate MediaItem object, and it is not my intention. I want this query to initiate the derived class, `PhotoMediaItem` or `VideoMediaItem`

Here's how my query looked like before the migration to Room, using the regular SQLiteHelper, and it worked just fine:

```
public ArrayList<MediaItem> getMediaListByAlbumId(int palbumId)
{
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try{
        ArrayList<MediaItem> mediaList = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT "+ mPhotoId +","+ mPhotoCreationDate +", 0 AS mediaType, '' FROM "+ mPhotosTableName + " WHERE " + this.mPhotoAlbumId + "="+palbumId +
                " UNION " +
                "SELECT "+ mVideoId +","+ mVideoCreationDate + " ,1 AS mediaType, " + mVideoLength + " FROM " + mVideosTableName + " WHERE " + this.mVideoAlbumId +"="+palbumId +
                " ORDER BY CreationDate DESC";
        cursor = mDB.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                // MediaHolder consists of the media ID and its type
                int mediaType = cursor.getInt(2);
                MediaItem mediaItem = null;
                if (mediaType == 0) {
                    mediaItem = new PhotoMediaItem(cursor.getInt(0), null, palbumId);
                } else if (mediaType == 1) {
                    mediaItem = new VideoMediaItem(cursor.getInt(0), null, palbumId, cursor.getLong(3));
                }
                mediaList.add(mediaItem);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return mediaList;
    }
    finally  {
        if(cursor != null){
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

}
```

How can I achieve the same effect using Room then?

Comment: "I can't really test this code unfortunately because I'm in a migration process" -- that code definitely will not work in a migration, as you cannot use Room DAOs in a migration. You have to use `SupportSQLiteDatabase` APIs. Unless the columns are identical between the two tables, your `SELECT *` would appear to violate `UNION` bylaws.

Comment: Also, Room cannot instantiate a `MediaItem`. AFAIK it will not know to instantiate anything else. So I would expect a compile-time failure on a `new MediaItem()` call.

Comment: @CommonsWare I already migrated the DB to Room. I edited my question. You're right Room gets compile time error. Room cannot instantiate `MediaItem`, I also don't want it to. I want Room to instantiate `PhotoMediaItem` or `VideoMediaItem`

Comment: Room doesn't know anything about that. How will it know at runtime which rows in your combined result set are supposed to be photos versus videos? From the `Cursor` that Room gets from SQLite, photos and videos look identical, with the same column names (whatever the first query has). You can have a `List<MediaItem> getAllMediaInAlbum(int albumId)` method in the DAO, but it will need to be a `@Transaction` that calls type-specific DAO methods: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/blob/v0.10/Trips/RoomPoly/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/room/TripStore.java#L120-L128

Comment: @CommonsWare I see, I have no problem creating a transaction. I looked into your example. But I'm still not sure how would it look like. I'm currently thinking that one query will return the photos and the second query will return the videos. but then how can I apply the "order by date" part? Does it have to be managed by java code with the `List`. or it can be accomplished with sql?

Comment: Since they would be separate queries, each subset would be sorted by date, but not the combination. You would need to sort it in code. Alternatively, consider whether you really want to have separate tables for these entities, if their structure is nearly identical.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hmm, I think that I cannot put these entities in the same table, because their structure is just nearly identical, and not totally identical. My end goal is that these objects will be `LiveData` based. Meaning that a change in the DB should result in a change in my `LiveData` list. This can be accomplished if I use `Transaction` and sort the objects in code?

Comment: @CommonsWare BTW, here's an article explaining how Entity Framework (in .NET) supports those type of queries. So practically it is possible to support these types of queries.https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

Comment: Why not just extract the common fields from `VideosMediaItem` and `PhotosMediaItem` to `MediaItem`?

Comment: @jaychang0917 ehm, and then what? `VideoMediaItem` and `PhotoMediaItem` have also different columns. and I need to get all of the data.

Comment: My question is how did you handled typeAdapters for Polymorphism?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you have a number of options here:

**Option 1**

You use a single table to store all `MediaItem`s and you use a discriminator column to make the difference between a video and a photo.
You have a single DAO method that performs the query, applies the `order by` and returns a `Cursor`. Then you can use your existing cursor manipulation logic to return a `List<MediaItem>`
It can look like this:

```
@Dao
public abstract class MediaItemDao() {

    @Query("you query here")
    protected Cursor getByAlbumIdInternal(int albumId);

    public List<MediaItem> getByAbumId(int albumId) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try{
            List<MediaItem> mediaList = new ArrayList<>();
            cursor = getByAlbumIdInternal(albumId);
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    // use the discriminator value here
                    int mediaType = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("you discriminator column name here"));
                    MediaItem mediaItem = null;
                    if (mediaType == 0) {
                        mediaItem = new PhotoMediaItem(cursor.getInt(0), null, palbumId);
                    } else if (mediaType == 1) {
                        mediaItem = new VideoMediaItem(cursor.getInt(0), null, palbumId, cursor.getLong(3));
                    }
                    mediaList.add(mediaItem);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return mediaList;
        }
        finally  {
            if(cursor != null){
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

You use two different tables to store `VideosMediaItem` and `PhotosMediaItem`. You have a `MediaItemDao` that has two internal methods to perform the queries and a single public method that merges the two result sets together and applies the sorting in java code. It can look like this:

```
@Dao
public abstract class MediaItemDao() {

    @Query("your query to get the videos, no order by")
    protected List<VideoMediaItem> getVideosByAlbumId(int albumId);

    @Query("your query to get the photos, no order by")
    protected List<PhotosMediaItem> getPhotosByAlbumId(int albumId);

    @Transaction
    public List<MediaItem> getByAlbumId(int albumId) {
        final List<MediaItem> mediaItems = new LinkedList<>();
        mediaItems.add(getVideosByAlbumId(albumId));
        mediaItems.add(getPhotosByAlbumId(albumId));
        Collections.sort(mediaItems, <you can add a comparator here>);
        return mediaItems;
    }
}
```

***EDIT: How to leverage live data for this option?***

As I mentioned, you should use `LiveData` as the return type of your protected methods so you get notified for underlying changes on those tables. So they should look like this:

```
protected LiveData<List<VideoMediaItem>> getVideosByAlbumId(int albumId);

protected LiveData<List<PhotosMediaItem>> getPhotosByAlbumId(int albumId);
```

In order to return a single `LiveData` to the client, you should zip the outputs of those two methods into a single stream. You can achieve this using a custom `MediatorLiveData` implementation. It may look like this:

```
public class ZipLiveData<T1, T2, R> extends MediatorLiveData<R> {

    private T1 mLastLeft;
    private T2 mLastRight;
    private Zipper<T1, T2, R> mZipper;

    public static final <T1, T2, R> LiveData<R> create(@NonNull LiveData<T1> left, @NonNull LiveData<T2> right, Zipper<T1, T2, R> zipper) {
        final ZipLiveData<T1, T2, R> liveData = new ZipLiveData(zipper);
        liveData.addSource(left, value -> {
            liveData.mLastLeft = value;
            update();
        });
        liveData.addSource(right, value -> {
            liveData.mLastRight = value;
            update();
        });
        return liveData;
    }

    private ZipLiveData(@NonNull Zipper<T1, T2, R> zipper) {
        mZipper = zipper;
    }

    private update() {
        final R result = zipper.zip(mLastLeft, mLastRight);
        setValue(result);
    }

    public interface Zipper<T1, T2, R> {

        R zip(T1 left, T2 right);

    }
}
```

Then you just use it in your repository public method like this:

```
public List<MediaItem> getByAlbumId(int albumId) {
    return ZipLiveData.create(
        getVideosByAlbumId(albumId),
        getPhotosByAlbumId(albumId),
        (videos, photos) -> {
            final List<MediaItem> mediaItems = new LinkedList<>();
            mediaItems.add(videos);
            mediaItems.add(photos);
            Collections.sort(mediaItems, <you can add a comparator here>);
            return mediaItems;
        }
}
```

**Option 3**

This is applicable only if you have a repository layer in place.

You use two different tables to store `VideosMediaItem` and `PhotosMediaItem`. You have a DAO class for each one. You have a repository that depends on the both DAOs and combines the result sets, applying the sorting. It can look like this:

```
@Dao
public abstract class VideosMediaItemDao {

    @Query("your query to get the videos, no order by")
    public List<VideoMediaItem> getByAlbumId(int albumId);

}

@Dao
public abstract class PhotosMediaItemDao {

    @Query("your query to get the photos, no order by")
    public List<PhotosMediaItem> getByAlbymId(int albumId);

}

public interface MediaItemRepository {

    public List<MediaItem> getByAlbumId(int albumId);

}

class MediaItemRepositoryImpl {

    private final VideosMediaItemDao mVideoDao;
    private final PhotosMediaItemDao mPhotoDao;

    MediaItemRepositoryImpl(VideosMediaItemDao videoDao, PhotosMediaItemDao photoDao) {
        mVideoDao = videoDao;
        mPhotoDao = photoDao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MediaItem> getByAlbumId(int albumId) {
        final List<MediaItem> mediaItems = new LinkedList<>();
        mediaItems.add(mVideoDao.getByAlbumId(albumId));
        mediaItems.add(mPhotoDao.getByAlbumId(albumId));
        Collections.sort(mediaItems, <you can add a comparator here>);
        return mediaItems;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very verbose answer. As to Option #1: Unfortunately, I cannot really put these in one table as the entities have some difference and I'm planning to extend their data later on, but I liked the idea very much. As to option #2: Can `List<MediaItem>` be wrapped as `LiveData`, so I'll be able to get change notifications to the underlying data in my DB?

Comment: @idish Yes, you can leverage the `LiveData` functionality, but it will be a bit complicated. You should use `LiveData<List<Type>>` as the return type of the two protected methods and create a custom `MediatorLiveData` implementation to zip the two inputs together. I will try and update my answer.

Comment: Amazing, looks like it works perfectly, great answer! Still sad that there's no support to query polymorphic entities in Room, as it could make this process much more simple and probably more efficient.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev Is there a way to make ZipLiveData more generic, ie I have ```TA1, TA2``` list and ```TB1, TB2, TB3``` list Do I have to create separate helper classes to zip live data for these lists or there is a way to create a single ZipLiveData class with dynamic type list in object creator?

Comment: @dipcore If you want to be able to work with more than 2 streams to be zipped, there is a way to do it. You can store their values in a list inside the `ZipLiveData`. The list can be of type `T` (if you want to limit your stream types to a common super type) or `Object` (if you want to zip arbitrary types). Then you pass the list of data to the `zip()` method of the zipper function. If you want to zip only after all of the streams have returned a result, you should put additional logic to verify the condition.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev Take a look on my solution below. Is that a good idea to store sources in hashmap and use ```source.toString()``` as a key?

Comment: @Jeffrey Just make sure to call your DAO method in a background thread. There are a number of libraries that can help you - RxJava, Kotlin coroutines, AsyncTasks, etc.

Comment: About opition1, how type convertors will be? Because on typeConvertor you have access to just that specific field not discriminator field. So how we can cast our object?

Answer (score 0):

I was playing a bit with it and seems found a generic solution to zip multiple LiveData sources together.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData

class ZipLiveData<S>(private val process: (List<S>) -> List<S>) : MediatorLiveData<List<S>>() {
    val map = hashMapOf<String, List<S>>()
    fun addSource(source: LiveData<*>) {
        addSource(source) {
            map[source.toString()] = it as List<S>
            value = process(map.values.flatten())
        }
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
    @Transaction
    fun findItems(albumId: Int): LiveData<List<MediaItem>> {
        val liveData = ZipLiveData<MediaItem> { it.sortedBy { item -> item.weight } }
        liveData.addSource(getVideosByAlbumId(albumId))
        liveData.addSource(getPhotosByAlbumId(albumId))
        liveData.addSource(getSoundsByAlbumId(albumId))
        return liveData
    }
```

Not sure if it's the most elegant solution though