# Inheritance in the Room Persistence Library

Tags: android, android-room

TL;DR: How can I store and retrieve objects of type `ClassA` and `ClassB` which both inherit from `ClassP` in the same "list", using the Room Persistence Library?

In other words, **How should I store a `List<? extends BaseAnimal>` in my Room DB?**

---

I have Animals, for the purpose of this question.

```
public abstract class BaseAnimal {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;

    public BaseAnimal(long id){this.id = id;}

    public abstract void func(int param);

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

An animal has an `id` and implements some function `func`. There will likely be many kinds of animals. To start with, I have an `Elephant` which additionally has a `trunkLength` property, and a `Giraffe` which additionally has a `neckLength` property.

```
public class Giraffe extends BaseAnimal {
    public long neckLength;

    public Giraffe(long id) {
        super(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void func(int param) {

    }
}
```

I have several instances of `Elephant` and `Giraffe` in my application. How can I, using the Android Room Persistence Library, store and retrieve them sorted by `BaseAnimal.id`?

---

### Expectations

At first, I hoped that it would be as simple as this:

- Annotate the `BaseAnimal` class with `@Entity(tableName = "base_animal_table")`
- Annotate my extension of the `RoomDatabase` with
      @Database(entities = {BaseAnimal.class }, version = 1)
- Add a function for inserting to the Data Access Object
      `@Insert
      void insertAnimal(BaseAnimal animal);`
- Add a method to the Repository

  ```
  public void insertAnimal(BaseAnimal animal){
          new insertAnimalAsyncTask(recipeDAO).execute(animal);
      }

  private static class insertAnimalAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<BaseAnimal, Void, Void> {

      private RecipeDAO mAsyncTaskDao;

      insertAnimalAsyncTask(RecipeDAO dao) {
          mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
      }

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(final BaseAnimal... params) {
          mAsyncTaskDao.insertAnimal(params[0]);
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```

I expected that this would lead to room generating a table named `base_animal_table` which would look somewhat like this (with some sample data):

```
| id | ElephantTrunkLength | GiraffeNeckLength |
| 0  | NULL                | 12                |
| 12 | 1337                | NULL              |
```

I also expected that I could retrieve the data from this table something like this:

```
// this is in the DAO
@Query("SELECT * from `base_animal_table` ORDER BY id ASC")
LiveData<List<BaseAnimal>> getAllAnimals();
```

and then get a list that contains both, entities of type `Elephant` with their `trunkLength` property set, and entities of type `Giraffe` with their `neckLength` set.
This seems not to be straightforward. How can I implement this?

---

One approach I see is the following, but I am not sure whether it is the best way. And I am also starting to doubt that Room makes this any easier than using plain SQLite. I tried to produce a working example for this approach with room, but there are still some unresolved issues.

### One Approach

Create a table `base_animals` which only contains the `id` and other base animal attributes, along with an indicator of their child type:

```
// base_animals
| id | animalType |
| 0  | "GIRAFFE"  |
| 12 | "ELEPHANT" |
```

Use this table to keep a list of all animals and their `id`s. Create a table `elephants` and a table `giraffes` with the `id` and their specific properties (`trunkLength` and `neckLength`, respectively).
Then we can store an animal in the DB by creating an entry in both the base table and the child table.
To retrieve a specific animal by `id`, we can now find the `animalType` in the `base_animals` table and with that decide in which child table - `elephants` or `giraffes` we need to search.

The problem I have with this approach is that it requires that I have to write quite some code and I have to update it whenever I create a new animal entity - e.g. a `Dolphin`.

So, my question is: **How should I store a `List<? extends BaseAnimal>` in my Room DB?**
I would prefer it if I could leave `BaseAnimal` an abstract class.

Comment: Hey, I think your problem is similar to this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972843/polymorphic-entities-in-room/52113714#52113714

Comment: Thanks @DanailAlexiev! It is really the same problem and the top answer there looks very promising. I have been attempting that answer's second option in the meantime without knowing this answer existed, and struggled with things that it seems to be explaining clearly. I'm excited to go try it again with that answer as guide :)

Comment: @lucidbrot if you have the authority now (4k rep) mark it as duplicate as I saw this comment by chance thought it's very useful and literally an answer to what I'm searching for :D

Comment: @OmarShawky Huh, I'm surprised to see that I was able to unilaterally close it as dupe. Thanks for suggesting to try again!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that using inheritance is a good idea here.
I would suggest using composition instead.

Keep a class named Animal (not BaseAnimal).

The animal should have a type just like you suggested.

Another table (AnimalProperties) would hold the properties of each animal.
It will have a foreign key to the Animals table and a property name and property value.

Now...

If this is all that you need, meaning a class with type and properties then you're all set.
But if you also need the class to behave differently like implementing a fly() method for a bird and run() a dog then you should consider using Composition to add behaviors to the Animal.

If you are not familiar with Composition have a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RiRrcCUyn4M) for a simple explanation.