# LiveData and room using inheritance

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have an app Im trying to write that has 3 objects that inherit from one object, all entities,
Im using room to store those locally.

In the dao of each entity I have "getAll" function that returnes a livedata<List>.

My question is,
is there a way, to get all of the lists from the database as one list (since they all inherit from the same class)?

Unless Im wrong, if I'll just use "getAll" on the superclass it wont give me the specific fields for every class.
and I have one recyclerView that holds those objects as 1 list so I need a way to combine them.

I tried looking it up but when it comes to inheritance its not really clear how Room handle stuff.(for example in the documentation google gives an example using inheritance with both objects having uniqe id's, but when i tried i got an error that the superclass id will be overwritten by the subclass id.).

If anyone could help, or provide a link to where i can learn more about it I'll greatly appriciate it.

Thanks, and have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this here in-case someone else needs it.

There are multiple ways to go about solving this one.

- The first one is using a POJO as "MikeT" stated on his answer.
- The second one is adding a "type" property to the superclass and get the whole
  superclass list, and on the runtime select the proper object and create it.(using
  the id since its the same).
  the downside is that you access the db multiple times which can reduce
  performance. (the solution I was going for before this morning)
- The third way(that I ended using) is in this post answer by "Danail Alexiev"
  [Polymorphic entities in Room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972843/polymorphic-entities-in-room)
  creating a custom MediatorLiveData implementation that zipps the 2 (or more)
  livedata objects and returns one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you could use a POJO (or perhaps a suitable Entity if one exists) that includes ALL fields and utilise a `getAll` @Query that includes a UNION. Of course the better way is to perhaps reconsider the design.

The following is an example of a Parent (**BaseObject**) from which 2 Objects are inherited, name **ChildType1** and **ChildType2**.

In this example a **ChildType2** to has 2 additional fields one of which a **ChildType1** has as it's only additional field. Hence a **ChildType2** is suitable for holding all the fields of a **ChildType1**.

However, to enable a **ChildType1** to be correctly extracted it has to ***mimic*** the additional field of the **ChildType2**. This can be done easily with the SQL in the `getAll()` method in the Dao **Alldao**.

The following is the code utilised:-

**BaseObject** from which the two ChildTypes inherit:-

```
class BaseObject {
    @ColumnInfo(name = BaseColumns._ID)
    Long id;
    String name;
    long createdTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    int type;
}
```

**ChildType1** :-

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {BaseColumns._ID})
class ChildType1 extends BaseObject {
    public static final int TYPE = 1;
    String ct1;
}
```

- As will be seen the id column (_id) has been inherited and later that it causes no issues.

**ChildType2** :-

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {BaseColumns._ID})
class ChildType2 extends BaseObject {
    public static final int TYPE = 2;
    String ct1;
    String ct2;
}
```

**AllDao** where All the Dao's have been coded :-

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {

    @Insert
    long insert(ChildType1 childType1);
    @Insert
    long insert(ChildType2 childType2);

    @Query("SELECT *, 'n/a' AS ct2 FROM ChildType1 UNION SELECT * FROM childtype2")
    List<ChildType2> getAll();
}
```

- The query being using a UNION of initially the childtype1 table filling in the missing **ct2** field with the value **n/a** and the childtype2 table. Note that id's will probably be duplicated so to utilise an id you would have to determine the respective type *(e.g. is ct2 = n/a then it's probably a ChildType1 (hence why I'd string suggest an indicator of the type which cannot be ambiguous))*.

The @Database **TheDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities = {ChildType1.class,ChildType2.class},version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDao getAllDao();

    private volatile static TheDatabase instance;

    public static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    TheDatabase.class,
                    "thedatabase.db"
            )
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
            instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And finally an Activity, **MainActivity** putting it all together to demonstrate :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    AllDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDao();
        ChildType1 c1_1 = new ChildType1();
        c1_1.name = "CT1 001";
        c1_1.ct1 = "This is a CT1 for CT1 001";
        c1_1.type = ChildType1.TYPE;
        dao.insert(c1_1);
        ChildType2 c2_1 = new ChildType2();
        c2_1.name = "CT2 002";
        c2_1.ct1 = "This is CT1 for CT2 002";
        c2_1.ct2 = "This is CT2 for CT2 002";
        dao.insert(c2_1);
        for(ChildType2 c: dao.getAll()) {
            Log.d("" +
                    "TYPEINFO",
                    "Name = " + c.name +
                            "\n\t Created = " + c.createdTimestamp +
                            "\n\t ID = " + c.id +
                            "\n\t type = " + c.type +
                            "\n\t CT1 = " + c.ct1 +
                            "\n\t CT2 = " + c.ct2
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

When run the log contains :-

```
D/TYPEINFO: Name = CT1 001
         Created = 1626589554
         ID = 1
         type = 1
         CT1 = This is a CT1 for CT1 001
         CT2 = n/a
D/TYPEINFO: Name = CT2 002
         Created = 1626589554
         ID = 1
         type = 0
         CT1 = This is CT1 for CT2 002
         CT2 = This is CT2 for CT2 002
```

i.e. both types of children have been extracted into a single List of objects that can contain ALL the fields.

Comment: I've considered this solution but I didnt want to clutter the app with "unnecessary" objects, as you said I started reconsidering my design but then, I found another solution that zips the 2 livedata lists together to get 1 livedata object and i do this on the repository layer, it prevents me from accessing the db twice and i get the object i need.
I've used this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972843/polymorphic-entities-in-room
found out about it around the time you answered so i didnt have the chance to close the post, anyways, thank you!